# Spring cloud contract : Unable to read the stubjar from Jfrog in consumer side code

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I am new to Spring cloud contract testing. I am to publish the stub jar to Jfrog artifactory from the producer side.

Following Gradle code:

```
publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        artifact("build/libs/provider-service-$version"+"-stubs.jar") {
            extension 'jar'
        }}}
repositories {
    maven {
        name 'libs-snapshot'
        url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/"
        credentials {
            username project.repoUser
            password project.repoPassword
        }
    }
}
```

}

But on the consumer side I am not able to read the jar.  I am getting the following error to read the jar.

Code:

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(ids = "com.test:provider-service:+:stubs:8082",
    consumerName = "contracts",
    properties = {"stubrunner.username=admin", "stubrunner.password=Cirrus123$"},
    stubsPerConsumer = true,
    stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.REMOTE,
    repositoryRoot = "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/")
```

**Error:**

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For groupId [com.test] artifactId [provider-service] and classifier [stubs] the version was not resolved! The following exceptions took place [org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataNotFoundException: Could not find metadata com.test:provider-service/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\aether-local7525112400154924089), org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata com.test:provider-service/maven-metadata.xml from/to remote0 (http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)]*

But I am using the correct credentials to connect to Jfrog

Comment: We already provide an artifact task called `verifierStubsJar`. Please try using it in your producer gradle setup. Also, verify if your gradle setup is correct, i.e., if artifacts the main application artifact jar can be found in the right directory in JFrog.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error, but my configuration is with maven. 
I have verified, the stubs.jar is able to download from Jfrog when I add it as a dependency to my pom (just to test). I don't see any problem with my credentials